# How to add functionality to navigate through poses [ROS2 Nav2]

Tags: ros-humble, plugin, nav2

I want to write a plugin for navigating through poses such that the robot executes certain actions after reaching the waypoints.
From the information available on plugins for waypoint behaviour of nav2 on the [nav2 docs page](https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/nav2_waypoint_follower-plugins/input_at_waypoint.html) - [this](https://github.com/DockDockGo/ddg_waitstep_at_waypoint) is what I came up with.

But from the looks of it this only works with WaypointFollower which is not the same as navigate_through_poses?
The documentation is a little unclear on what exactly to do. It looks like I was headed in some wrong direction and the documentation to add a waypoint behaviour is either outdated or obscured.

I am having a tough time figuring out what I need to modify/add in order for nav_through_poses to do certain behaviours on reaching waypoints.

Any help would be hugely appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write a plugin for navigating through poses such that the robot executes certain actions after reaching the waypoints.

That's potentially the role of the waypoint follower, which is designed specifically to do that. Though, you can always do that via NavigateThroughPoses API as well if you choose, but you'll need to create a behavior tree that does that to your actions' specification. That should be relatively straightforward, but will need to learn a bit about behavior trees.

Since "go to a point, then execute a thing" is very sequential, that's why I made the waypoint follower (also because people kept asking for it and I cave to peer pressure ;-) ).

> the documentation to add a waypoint behaviour is either outdated or obscured.

I don't know what that means - can you be more specific? I intentionally spent time to [make these examples](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_waypoint_follower/plugins) for the purpose of providing self documented examples.